# Memory mapping physical disks and volumes

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-xp, memory-mapped-files

In Windows it's possible to open devices and volumes via `CreateFile()`. I've used this successfully before to `ReadFile()` from devices, but now I want to switch to memory-mapping. In the following code, I receive `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` for the value of `b`, and `c` is set to `87`, `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`.

```
HANDLE a = ::CreateFileA("\\\\.\\h:", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY | FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING, NULL);
HANDLE b = ::CreateFileMappingA(a, NULL, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, NULL);
DWORD c = ::GetLastError();
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't.  CreateFileMapping can only create a mapping to a file.  Take a look at the difference in the documentation between the hFile parameter for [ReadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365467%28VS.85%29.aspx) and for [CreateFileMapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366537%28VS.85%29.aspx).  For ReadFile it lists all the different types of handles it accepts (which includes devices), for CreateFileMapping it only lists files.